# How to mark a network as unreachable?

Tags: linux, routing

I have a router running Linux. Its network configuration has a default route to my ISP for public Internet access. I now need to prevent a specified destination network from access.

Original route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.6.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0.2
10.99.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
```

Assuming 74.1.1.0/24 is the network which I want to forbid routing. I hope every client connected to this router gets 'Network unreachable' for an address in that network.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: null route the network on the default gateway.

Comment: http://myeasylinux.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/null-route/

Comment: @GregoryA.Lussier , thanks for your link. However, the client just report 'timeout' instead of 'destination network unreachable'.

Comment: Then use the **REJECT** target of iptables, see this link: http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4550.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use iproute2.

```
ip route add unreachable 74.1.1.0/24
```

In this case, if you're trying to deny *outbound* traffic to that network, it's better to use routing to deny that network, rather than netfilter. For *inbound*, it's more idiomatic to use netfilter, as in another answer here, but with `--src` instead of `--dst`, and had better use ICMP admin prohibited, or just drop instead. You can use the RPDB (see `ip-rule(8)`, to achieve the same effect but likely will look out of place.

Don't use ifconfig, route, or other tools from the `net-tools` package; they're long deprecated.

You can confirm what the router itself will use as the routing decision.

```
$ ip route get 74.1.1.0/24
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

Note that the 'get' verb is not the same as 'show' (or 'list'), as it 'calculates' the routing decision rather than just filtering and listing entries in the routing table.

Hosts on your side of the network will get ICMP destination net unreachable.

```
$ ping 74.1.1.1 -c 1
PING 74.1.1.1 (74.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.6.254 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable

--- 74.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0.7ms
$ echo $?
1
```

If the userspace involved is defective and hangs rather than returning an error immediately, that's another problem. The kernel can't compensate for such buggy userspace.

Answer (score 4):

You can use netfilter

```
iptables -A FORWARD --dst 74.1.1.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable
```

`man iptables` says the following about the `--reject-with` option

```
--reject-with type
     The type given can be icmp-net-unreachable, icmp-host-unreachable,
     icmp-port-unreachable,  icmp-proto-unreachable,  icmp-net-prohibited,
     icmp-host-prohibited  or  icmp-admin-prohibited  (*)  which  return  the
     appropriate  ICMP  error  message (port-unreachable is the default).  The
     option tcp-reset can be used on rules which only match the TCP protocol:
     this causes a TCP RST packet to be sent back.  This is mainly useful for
     blocking ident (113/tcp) probes which frequently occur when sending mail to
     broken mail hosts (which won't accept your mail otherwise)
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Add a route pointing to `lo` for that subnet:</strike>

`route add -net 74.1.1.0/24 gw 127.0.0.1 lo`

The `ip` command has  a `blackhole` parameter I just found out about:

`ip route add blackhole 74.1.1.0/24`

[Read more](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-drop-or-block-attackers-ip-with-null-routes.html).

Looks like there's a `reject` option - see if that does what you need:

`route add -net 74.1.1.0/24 reject`

Comment: A blackhole route will silently drop the packets sent to destination network instead return 'destination network unreachable' :-(

Comment: See above edits.

Comment: Yes, looks like it..!

Comment: @ultrasawblade I tried that command and it seems the clients just reports 'timed out' instead the expected 'network unreachable' :-(

Answer (score 0):

REJECT = knock at the door , you holler go away!.

DROP = knock at the door , you sit quietly and the visitor leaves , :theory?..:P

depends on what your trying to achieve , my opinion is

REJECT says to someone to try and further the conversation till ACCEPT is achieved
 DROP says nothing , there for rendering any more conversation  CLOSED ,:up2you:).

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.